# Momentjs - Is there a way to get ISOdate from a relative time

Tags: momentjs

I am currently playing with `momentjs` and I would like to know if there is any reverse operation on relative times. For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
var relativeTime = moment([2007, 0, 29]).fromNow(); // returns "6 years ago" 
var date = moment(relativeTime).toDate();    // use date later somewhere
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, moment.js doesn't currently offer this functionality.

However, you are in luck.  [Sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/dates) can do this.

```
Date.create('6 years ago')
```